# Underlining a span element

Tags: html, css

When I apply 'border-bottom' to a 'span' element to underline it and if that the 'span' has 'image' in it with 'vertical-align: middle', the border cuts across the image!
Is there anyway to maintain 'vertical-align: middle' and still run the border below the 'span'?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.underline {
                font-size: 20px;
                border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
            }
            img.embeddedImage {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="underline"> (a) <img class="embeddedImage" src="logo.gif"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `{text-decoration:underline;}` ?

Comment: 'text-decoration:underline' underlines only the text portion of the 'span' and not the 'image' part!

Comment: you should put your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to your span or turn the span into a div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ehjFX/)**.

**Or**...use display:inline-block;

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ehjFX/1/)**.

Comment: I would recommend using `<div>` over `display:block;`, since that case would just be altering a `<span>` element to behave like a `<div>`, a practice which just introduces confusion. If using `display:inline-block;` then it would be fine with either element.

Comment: Which is why it says in my answer "or turn the span into a div."

Comment: 'display:inline-block' did the trick... thanks a lot! I didn't use 'display:block' because in this case the underline stretches to the end of the window!

Answer (score 3):

```
span.underline {
                font-size: 20px;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
```

Comment: text-decoration:underline underlines only the text portion of the 'span' and not the 'image' part!

Answer (score 2):

```
span { border-bottom: 1px solid; }​
```

[Fiddle up](http://jsfiddle.net/FBRtE/4/)

Comment: text-decoration:underline underlines only the text portion of the 'span' and not the 'image' part!

Comment: Ahh, didn't understand that was for image... fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If just underlining the text isn't enough... 
`{text-decoration:underline;}`

If you set the image to have a higher z-index higher than the span, does it do what you need?

```
    <style type="text/css">
        span.underline {
            font-size: 20px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        img.embeddedImage {
            vertical-align: middle;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    </style>
```